# Infinite sum of indicators almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere

> Let $S_{n}:= \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i,n}$ where for each $n, X_{1,n},  X_{2,n},..., X_{n,n}$ are sequences of independents r.v.'s. 
>   $$X_{i,n}=\begin{cases}1, & \text{with probability }p_n\\0,& \text{with probability }1-p_n\end{cases}$$ for $i = 1,\dots, n$. Suppose that $p_{n}={\beta}/n$.
>
> The problem is to show that $S_{n}$ doesn't converge almost surely to a limit.

I proved that it converges in distribution to the Poisson, but I'm not sure how to proceed in proving that $S_{n}$ does not converge almost surely to a limit. The hint given is to show that $ P(|S_{m}-S_{n}|>1) $ does not converge to zero. I know this is a Cauchy so possible giving me guidance in this directions. (or any other that you see fit)??

Thanks!!

Comment: Also, you know that if it converged to a limit it should be to a Poisson R.V. (if your calculationis right) ,since almost sure convergence implies convergence in distribution. Maybe supposing there is such R.V. you could get a contradiction?

Comment: I mean I'm almost sure it converges in distribution unless I missed something. $S_{n}$ is binomial. as n goes to infinity $p_{n}$ goes to zero, and $n*p_{n} = {beta}$. So then I just used the binomial approximation to the Poisson.

Comment: ok, contradiction argument. if poisson then it's memoryless so if $S_{n}$ converged to ${\beta}$ the probability of $S_{n}> {\epsilon}$ i.o =0 . But this contradicts the fact that it's restarts at each point??

Comment: "if poisson then it's memoryless" Sorry but what on Earth are you alluding to?

Comment: The memoryless property of a poisson point process

Comment: Where is there a Poisson **process** in this exercise? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: The #of arrivals at time $S_{n}$ and the number of arrivals at time $S_{n+1}$. But again I'm stuck @Did

Comment: @Max sorry forgot to tag

Comment: And this process is certainly not Poisson, since $S_{n+1}-S_n$ is always $0$ or $1$ (to be compared to Poisson random variables, which take any nonnegative integer value with positive probability).

Comment: @Did could you provide intuition on how to proceed with problem//

Comment: Here is a hint: Assume first that $X_{i,n}$ does not depend on $n$ and let $n<m$, what is the exact value of $P(S_m=S_n)$?

Comment: (1) $P(S_{m}=S_{n})=P(S_{m}=k|S_{n}=k)=P(S_{m} =k)$  (2) $P(S_{m}{\neq }S_{n}) =1-P(S_{m} =k)=\begin{equation} 1-e^{-\beta}{\beta}^k/k! \end{equation}$ (3)$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\begin{equation} (1-e^{-\beta}{\beta}^k/k!) \end{equation}=n(1-e^{-\beta}{\beta}^k/k!)\xrightarrow[]{} {\infty} $ (4) Use Borell Cantelli-2 show $P(S_{m}{\neq }S_{n}, i.o ) =1$, then show by 0-1 law $P(S_{m}=S_{n}, eventually) =0 $  @Did

Comment: Sorry but (1)-(2)-(3) are, each on its own, pure fantasy. In (1), for example, how is it possible that $P(S_m=S_n)$, dependent on $(n,m)$ only, suddenly becomes $P(S_m=k)$, dependent on $(m,k)$ only?

Comment: well for $S_{n}$ & $S_{m}$ to be equal they both should be equal to some number k. Should it be $ P(S_{n}=k)P(S_{m}=k)$ @Did

Comment: Let me suggest to stick to the exact wording of my comment. That one can seemingly choose any $k$ to evaluate $P(S_m=S_n)$ should make you suspect your approach is totally flawed. No, $P(S_m=S_n)$ is neither $P(S_m=k)$ nor $P(S_m=k)P(S_n=k)$ for some mysterious unspecified $k$. Once again: how to evaluate $P(S_m=S_n)$ in the setting of my comment dated 2016-01-30 13:25:57?

Comment: @Did honestly can't think of it. Could you direct me to the section/wiki/(chapter of any book) of probability which deals with two rvs being equal so i can review? unless your talking about $S_{n}$ & $S_{m} $limit being equal

Comment: Or the difference X=$S_{n+1}$-$S_{n}$ <epsilon

Comment: Note that $S_m=S_n$ iff $X_{n+1}=\cdots=X_m=0$ hence $P(S_m=S_n)=$ $_____$.